# How to fix " EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream" " error in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, eventsource

I'm setting up a web interface and I want the server to send data dynamically to update graphs. I found SSE (Server Sent Event), but I don't know how to use it. I try and retry but each time I got this error : "EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection." How can this works ?

I already try to find if and other content type is define but it's not.
I know than the .on(event, function) doesn't catch the event.

Here some of my code : 
        import path from 'path';
        import express from "express"
        import config from './config.js'
        import Frontend from "./frontend/frontend.module"
        import Backend from "./backend/backend.module"

```
    const EventEmitter = require('events');
    var app = new express();

    const Stream = new EventEmitter();

    //Try to configure SSE
    app.get('/stream', function(request, response){
        response.writeHead(200, {
          'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
          'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
          'Connection': 'keep-alive'
        });
        Stream.on("push", function(event, data) {
            console.log("RESPONSE 0");
            response.write("event: " + String(event) + "\n" + "data: " + JSON.stringify(data) + "\n\n");
            response.send();
            response.end(); 
            console.log("RESPONSE 1") ;
          });
        });


      setInterval(function(){
        Stream.emit("push", "test", { msg: "admit one" });
        console.log("\nEMIT");
      }, 5000)

    //Stop Trying here


    app.use(function(req, res, next){
        console.log(req.url);
        next();
    });

    // Import sub-apps
    app.use("/api", Backend.App)
    app.use("/", Frontend.App)

    // Enable CORS (for debugging -- better way?)

    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        next();
    })


    // Point static path to dist
    app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app/assets')));

    // Point static path to dist
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

    const port = process.env.PORT || config.port;
    app.listen(port, function () {
        console.log('Server listening on port ' + port);
    });
```

And I have the client listening :

```
    var es = new EventSource("http://127.0.0.1:8081/") ;
    es.onmessage = function(event){
        console.log("ONMESSAGE "+event.data);
    }
```

I read many post about this error but I can't find the solution, please can someone help me ?

Comment: Could you get a solution to this?